# Is there a way to make a set of all real numbers within a range?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, logic, sets

Is there a way to create a set of all real numbers within a range? For example, the range between 1300 and 1500, including 1500 in normal distribution. Thank you very much.

My problem exactly:

- $A$ – The probability of rainfall/year being less than or equal to 1500 is $P[A]=0.17$
- $B$ – The probability of rainfall/year being between 1300 and 1700 (including 1700) is $P[B]= 0.33$
- $C$ – The probability of rainfall/year being less than, or equal to 1700 is $P[C]= 0.39$

What's the probability of P[A Intersection B]?

By hand, I solved this by defining the respective sets and making operations between them and from that, computing probabilities.

Comment: Mathematica does not have a general "set type", so technically it is not possible to create any kind of set.  But very likely it *is* possible to solve the problem you have, you just need to state the problem clearly.  Can you explain what are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to define three sets like that, assign probabilities to them and then make operations with them, for example P[AUB], where A is the above mentioned set and B is the set for all reals lower or equal to 1700.

Comment: Yes, and all I found and tried was using Lists, but that's only for a specific n amount of numbers with a specific step, for example List[0,1500] creates a set of all integers between 0 and 1500

Comment: What do you mean by "assign probabilities to a set"?  You can define distributions over various intervals.  Take a look at `ProbabilityDistribution` and the many other built-in distributions: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ParametricStatisticalDistributions.html http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ProbabilityAndStatistics.html  I still don't understand your question though. It is best if you give a *concrete* example: "this is my input, this is the operation I want to do, this is the output I expect".

Comment: The sets represent events, each of these events has a certain probability of occurring. There is the event that the rainfall per year is less than, or equal to 1500 and its probability is 0.17. That's my example exactly.

Comment: I am voting to close this question until it gets clarified.  Consider giving an example of the sort I mentioned: what is your starting data, what operation you want to perform, and what result do you expect. If you like, work out a simple example by hand, then we can think about how to do the same with Mathematica for complicated cases.  Please use the edit link below the question to edit (rewrite) it.  Do not use the comments to clarify the question, re-write the original post instead. Make it clear without having to read any comments.

Comment: You are not giving any information on the problem you are trying to solve. What is it that you are trying to actually do? For example do you just want to sample from your rain distribution? (`rainDist = UniformDistribution[{0, 1500}]; RandomVariate[rainDist, 5]`).  Provide complete information and some code you have tried.

Comment: edited, sorry for late response

Comment: If the probability that less than 1500 mm will fall is 0.17, how can the probability that between 1300 and 1500 mm will fall be *greater than 0.17*?  $x \in [1300, 1500]$ implies that $x \le 1500$.

Comment: Have a look at [RandomVariate](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomVariate.html) and [Random Number Generation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/RandomNumberGenerationOverview.html)

Comment: mistyped, it's between 1300 and 1700. Thank you for your time!

Comment: I think the best way to solve this is to convert to a system of equations by hand, and solve that. Problems specified in this format will usually be underdetermined.  This one is solvable because it happens to hold that $A \cup B = C$.  Do you have a very large number of such intervals to work with?  If yes, can you give more information about them, including: are you certain that there is enough information to have a unique solution, like in the example?

Comment: Just to clarify: I don't believe Mathematica has any functions which take the problem exactly in this format.  But it should be possible to solve it manually by breaking down the biggest intervals containing all your sets into disjoint pieces, assigning a (symbolic) probability to each, and write a system of equations in terms of these.

Comment: Yep, I had done that manually by hand and it looks like there's no other way in Mathematica. Thank you for your time again.